# Convert IList<T> to IList<MyObjectType>

Tags: c#, casting

I coded this interface

```
public interface IRepository
    {

        IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
    }
```

And I have this classes

```
public class Customer
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BusinessArea { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
           foreach (var line in this.data)
            {
                string[] CustomerData = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+(?=002#)");
                foreach (var CustomerItem in CustomerData)
                {
                    string[] d = Regex.Split(CustomerItem, "#");
                    yield return new Customer() { BusinessArea = d[3], CNPJ = d[1], Name = d[2]                          };
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I would like to use GetAll for load Others classes, but the compiler show this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Prova.Domain.Customer' to 'T'"

I've tried to do Cast using (T) but I can't solve this. How can I solve this Generic Cast?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository should be generic, not just the method:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        foreach (var line in this.data)
        {
            string[] CustomerData = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+(?=002#)");
            foreach (var CustomerItem in CustomerData)
            {
                string[] d = Regex.Split(CustomerItem, "#");
                yield return new Customer() { BusinessArea = d[3], CNPJ = d[1], Name = d[2] };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As your `CustomerRepository` is providing a specific implementation for `Customer` objects, the method itself cannot remain generic, as you are observing.

Comment: Got it! Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`IRepository` should be generic (`IRepository<T>`) and `CustomerRepository` should implement `IRepository<Customer>`:

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Custom>
```

You would then create another repository that implements `IRepository<Other>` and returns `Other` objects.

Generics is about compile-time safety. It's not about "converting" from one type to another.

Answer (score 1):

Specify generic in your interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
```

as well as in your class:

```
public class CustomerRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```